# Could this PC handle more than 16gb of ram?

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, motherboard

Ideally, I'd like to install 32GB on this machine, if possible can someone suggest? I've seen two different 'limits' mentioned 8GB and 16GB but others suggest if the OS is 64bit and the board has the slots, it should work.

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
Motherboard: Acer RS880M05
Processor: AMD Athlon II X4 645
Chipset: AMD 880G Rev. 00
Southbridge: AMD SB850 Rev. 40
LPCIO: ITE IT8721
BIOS: AMI P01-B4

Specifies: DDR3 1.5V 1333/1066 Un-buffered Non-ECC DIMM

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You know there are specialist websites for asking that exact question. https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/advisor

Answer (score 0):

This motherboard by doing a quick google search only supports up to 16GB 1066/1333 DDR3. It will not support 32GB. Everything else is not really relevant, it all depends on the mobo, but yes you would need 64 bit windows. :)